# A Simons' type inequality

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I have a problem with the inequality (5) in the article 'Estimates for stable minimal surfaces in three dimensional manifolds' of R.Schoen. As the author suggests this inequality comes from 'well known' equations of the article 'Curvature estimates for minimal hypersurfaces' of Schoen-Simom-Yau. I use [S] to denote the first article and [SSY] for the second one.

Now i think that the only usefull inequality in [SSY] for proving (5) of [S] is the inequality (1.27) that can be rewritten in the following form:

$\Delta |A|^2 \geq 2|\nabla A|^2-c(1+|A|^2)^2 $ where $ c$ depends only on curvatures of $ N$.

This inequality holds for every point in $ M $. In [SSY] the authors restict the study on points of $ M $ where the second fundamental form is non vanishing, but for the inequality above this restriction is clearly not necessary. All things made in [SSY] below (1.27) are restricted to $ |A| \neq 0 $, so they are not useful for proving (5) of [S] that it holds globally on $ M $.

Thank you